# javascript cannot access 'a' before initialization

Tags: javascript

```
r = {
  name:'Bart',
  location:'Springfield' 
}

for(var a in r) {
  if (r.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
      console.log(a);
      const {a} = r[a]; // Here's where it's  failing.
      //I'm trying to do the equivalent of const{name} = r[a];
  }
}

console.log(name) //Expecting output `Bart`
```

In my attempt to destructure an object, I've attempted what's above. However, this gives me 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization`

Do you see any way using which this could be solved?

Comment: Use a different variable name in the loop.

Comment: Don't use a `const` and `var` with the same name in the same block-level scope

Comment: Actually `a` is `name`. I'm trying to the same thing as {name} = r[a] just like it's done in destructuring.

Answer (score 4):

On this line

```
const {a} = r[a];
```

You are trying to define a new variable `a`, which depends on using `a` to access a property of `r`.

Also, `const { a }` means you are trying to access the property `a` of r[a]. This can only work if `r[a]` returns an object which also has it's own keys to destructure like so:

```
r = {
  name: { a: 'Bart' },
  location: { a: 'Springfield' } 
}
```

In your code `r[a]` will return the values, which are both strings. This means they don't have a property `a` that you can destructure.
In which case, I assume you meant to just assign it to a variable, instead of destructuring

To avoid the error, try to avoid naming conflicts, perhaps by using more readable variable names and skip the destructuring like so:

```
for(var key in r) {
  if (r.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(key);
      const a = r[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: If I change `a` to `x` I now now get `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined`

Comment: Duplicate identifier is so obvious one tends to overlook another (not small) problem here. `const {a} = r[key]` is not what you want as it tries to access non-existing property `a` of `r[key]` which is a string.

Comment: @SonNguyen wow, I can't believe I missed that. I'll edit my answer to include that

Answer (score 0):

```
r = {
  name:'Bart',
  location:'Springfield' 
}
```

`r.name` contains `'Bari'` (string type) value not any **Object value**. So distructuring causes problem in your statement `const {a} = r[a]` as `r[a]` isn't an object. And remember **const** and **let** are always scope bound.
A possible workaround would be as follows

```
var r = {
  name:'Bart',
  location:'Springfield' 
}

for(var a in r) {
  if (r.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
      globalThis[a] = r[a];
  }
}

console.log(name)
```

Comment: console.log(name) should be `Bart`

Comment: @Norman, see my updated changes. Is it what you want?