# Can't deploy to Heroku because of babel/replEval issue

Tags: javascript, heroku, babeljs

I am having an issue when I try to deploy to Heroku my webpack/django and react app. I followed the heroku documentation for building docker images with heroku.yml but when I try git push to heroku, it gives the error at step 5/7. Is there some compatibility issue? Couldn't find anything online with a similar problem.

Commands I am running:

```
git add heroku.yml

git commit -m "Add Heroku.yml"

heroku stack:set container

git push heroku [branch-name]:main
```

error:

```
remote:  ---> Running in 0b74133d0113
remote: 
remote: > rsm_app@0.1.0 babel /
remote: > babel-node --presets=@babel/preset-env,@babel/preset-react
remote:
remote: /node_modules/@babel/node/lib/_babel-node.js:222
remote:     eval: replEval,
remote:           ^
remote:
remote: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'replEval' before initialization
remote:     at replStart (/node_modules/@babel/node/lib/_babel-node.js:222:11)
remote:     at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/@babel/node/lib/_babel-node.js:179:5)
remote:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
remote:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
remote:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
remote:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)
remote:     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! rsm_app@0.1.0 babel: `babel-node --presets=@babel/preset-env,@babel/preset-react`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the rsm_app@0.1.0 babel script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-11-08T06_05_13_384Z-debug.log
remote: The command '/bin/sh -c npm run babel' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Your error is (as you say) `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'replEval' before initialization`. This is not a Git error and not a Heroku error; it seems to be a JavaScript error. Git is acting as a messenger and is not relevant. Heroku is acting as the build software and is relevant in that it's following your build instructions, but this seems to be a basic JS programming error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript cannot access 'a' before initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527782/javascript-cannot-access-a-before-initialization)

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in `@babel/node` ([issue report](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15123)) fixed [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/15124). You will need to update to v7.20.3 when it's published (or use a Git URI as the dependency).